# Adding table to LWC Input Rich Text

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputrichtext

I am using the standard LWC Input Richtext component. I have extended it to add Table toolbar icon. I am injecting the Table html based on number of rows and cols user enters:

[image]

and when I hit save , table is injected to the rich text value:

[image]

and this is the inspected code with injected table:

[image]

But as soon as I hit a backspace, it removes the total table.
**(this happens even when we copy paste the table to Input Rich Text component)**.

So I have disabled the backspace event on window:

```
  connectedCallback() {
    this.getEmails();
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
  }

  handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key == "Backspace") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
```

but no luck, as the table is removed even before my event is handled.
I did a bit of digging and found the quillJs event handler is culprit which removes the total table on backspace. Event handler shown below (which is on qlEditor and we dont have access to as it is quillJs). I can remove it from debug session and backspace works great when I remove it.

[image]

Now the question is - is it possible to remove this event handler programmatically ? It is neither the window event nor the event I have created so I couldn't get access to it.

I could use quillJs instead but thats the last resort.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks